# Remove a query string using react-router without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

In my application I have a query string that I want to remove after a button click.

I get the query string like this:

```js
  import qs from 'query-string'
  // ..

  const { search } = url
  const { id } = qs.parse(search)
```

Then when I click on the button, I want to remove the string without reloading the page.

```js
  const onClick = () => {
     history.push({})
  }
```

However the code above doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to replace the state with a call to [`replace`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history). The call to push will add a new entry to the history which break the previous button. The call to replace don't push but replace the current page.

```
const onClick = () => {
  history.replace(pathWithoutTheQuery)
}
```